# Pseudo element and z-index

Tags: css

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/d7qub9e4/)

On hover I need a pseudo element to fade in. This is achieved with:

```
li:before{
  content: url("http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/tatice/operating-systems/128/Globe-icon.png");
  position: absolute;
  z-index: -1;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: opacity .2s ease-in-out;
  top: -40px;
  left: -40px;
}

li:hover:before{
  opacity: 1;
  transition: opacity .2s ease-in-out;
}
```

The issue is, that the pseudo image appears above the item preceding it in the list. How can I fix this? i've tried playing around with the z-index but with no luck.

### EDIT

Just to clarify:

globe should appear behind the rainbow circle - every rainbow circle

Comment: You need the 'globe' to appear above the 'rainbow circle'?

Comment: Who needs to be in front of who?

Comment: globe should appear behind the rainbow circle - every rainbow circle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't assign the `li` a `z-index`.

By assigning a `z-index` you weren't letting the browser assign and adjust the stacking order properly.

```css
li:before {
  content: url("http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/tatice/operating-systems/128/Globe-icon.png");
  position: absolute;
  z-index: -1;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: opacity .2s ease-in-out;
  top: -40px;
  left: -40px;
}

li:hover:before {
  opacity: 1;
  transition: opacity .2s ease-in-out;
}

li {
  margin: 10px;
  display: inline;
  position: relative;

}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>
    <img src="http://demo.chimerathemes.com/wp-content/themes/apppress/images/icons/included/color.png">
  </li>
  <li>
    <img src="http://demo.chimerathemes.com/wp-content/themes/apppress/images/icons/included/color.png">
  </li>
  <li>
    <img src="http://demo.chimerathemes.com/wp-content/themes/apppress/images/icons/included/color.png">
  </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
li:before {
    pointer-events: none;
}
li:hover {
    z-index: 0;
}
```

First css part is to make it only work on rainbow hover instead of rainbow+globe hover. Second part is to make the hovered list item below the other list items resulting in the globe being behind the other list items.

Comment: This is good, but not quite there - when you hover off a color circle, the globe jumps above the other colored circles.

Comment: Does not work at your link - hover over the colored circle in the middle, then move off it, watch as the globe goes in front of the colored circle on the left.